# Checking if the first character of all the strings are same or not in a array of strings

Tags: c++

I have an array of strings, I want to check whether the first characters of all the strings are the same or not.

I know how to retrieve the first character of a string, by this method

```
char first_letter;
first_letter = (*str)[0];
```

Initially, I thought to go the brute force way, by checking for the first letter for every strings, using a nested for loop.

```
 int flag = 0
 char f1,f2;
 for(int i = 0;i < size_arr - 1;i++){
   f1 = (*str[i])[0];
   for(int j = i + 1;j < size_arr;j++){
     f2 = (*str[j])[0];
     if(f1 != f2)
       flag += 1;
    }
}
if(!(flag))
  cout<<"All first characters same";
else
  cout<<"Different";
```

But I need an approach to find whether the first letters of all the strings present in an array are the same or not. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: If you find two characters that are not equal, why do you keep searching?

Comment: You don't need a nested loop.  Just pick the first letter of the first string and then compare all the other strings to that.

Comment: What is your declaration for `str`?  The only way ``(*str[i])[0]`` can give you the first character is if it's an array of pointers to std::string (or some other object that can be indexed) - like maybe `std::string *str[10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't use a nested for loop.Rather modify your code this way

```cpp
for(int i = 0;i < size_arr - 2;i++){
   f1 = (*str[i])[0];
   f2 = (*str[i+1])[0];
   if( f1!=f2 ){
      printf("not same characters at first position");
      break;
      flag=1;
   }
}
if(flag==0)printf("same characters at first position");
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this C approach for you (it's because you have used character arrays here, not `std::string` of C++ – so it's convenient to describe using C code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 128

int main(void) {
    char string[][MAX_LENGTH] = {"This is string ONE.", "This one is TWO.",
                                 "This is the third one."};
    char first_letter = string[0][0];
    int total_strs = sizeof(string) / sizeof(string[0]);
    int FLAG = 1;

    // Iterate through each letter of each string
    for (int i = 0; i < total_strs; i++)
        // First letter of the string is equal to first_letter?
        if (string[i][0] != first_letter) {

            FLAG = 0; // set to 0 as soon as it finds
            break;    // the initial_letter is NOT equal to the first
        }             // letter

    if (FLAG)
        fprintf(stdout, "The strings have the same initial letters.\n");
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "Not all strings have the same initial letters.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to convert it to a C++ code, no big issue – just replace `stdio.h` with `iostream`, `int FLAG = 1` with `bool FLAG = true`, `fprintf()` to `std::cout` statements, that's it.

In case you need to work with `std::string` for the same job, just simply get the array of those strings, set the flag as true by default, iterate through each string, and match in case the first string's initial letter is equivalent to others, eventually, mark the flag as false in as soon as a defected string is found.

---

The program will display (if same initial vs. if not):

```
The strings have the same initial letters.
Not all strings have the same initial letters.
```

Comment: I don't think he is using C strings - the only way `(*str[i])[0]` can give him the first letter of a string is if it's an array of pointers to std::string (or some other object that can be indexed).  For example, `std::string *str[10]` would allow `(*str[i])[0]`  Or maybe he is wrong aboutr knowing how to get the first character - it would help if he showed the declaration of `str`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yep. You're right. Not showing the declaration to visitors is a bad choice and leads to ambiguity when answering.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I've amended the answer by adding an explanation about the same work in the C++ approach since it's less hard than that of C, the code itself clarifies the base idea.